# VBA loop for calling files in a folder

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I'm trying to create a macro which compares text files. However, I need a loop to compare all the files within a folder.

The macro I have now only compares between template1 and spool1 for example.
I need a loop that compares template1 with spool1.. template2 with spool2 etc. Any idea on how to do so?

I think I have to add the files into a collection first and then call it.. I'm not sure though.

Here's my codes

```
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "D:\Users\tmp4jj\Desktop\ComparisonTool\"
Dim template1 As Word.Document
Dim spool1 As Word.Document
Set template1 = Documents.Open("D:\Users\tmp4jj\Desktop\ComparisonTool\template1.docx")
Set spool1 = Documents.Open("D:\Users\tmp4jj\Desktop\ComparisonTool\spool1.txt")

Application.CompareDocuments OriginalDocument:=Documents("template1.docx") _
    , RevisedDocument:=Documents("spool1.txt"), Destination:= _
    wdCompareDestinationNew, Granularity:=wdGranularityWordLevel, _
    CompareFormatting:=False, CompareCaseChanges:=True, CompareWhitespace:= _
    False, CompareTables:=True, CompareHeaders:=True, CompareFootnotes:=True, _
     CompareTextboxes:=True, CompareFields:=True, CompareComments:=True, _
    CompareMoves:=False, RevisedAuthor:="UOB", IgnoreAllComparisonWarnings:= _
    False
```

Thanks in advance as I'm very new to coding!

Comment: Do the templateX.docx and and spoolX.txt always correspond to each other, or do you need to check all combinations? Is it working otherwise?

Comment: Yes, they do correspond to each other. I need templateX to be compared with spoolX, templateY with spoolY for example. The macro I have now only compairs a pair of documents, I need a loop to run through the whole folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop comparison macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767537/loop-comparison-macro)

Answer (score 0):

If the filenames always correspond, you can use the Dir$() function with a wildcard to find one or the other of the pair, then build the other filename out of the result.  Dir$() returns the next result on subsequent calls, and then an empty String when all the files have been returned.  This makes it easy to build a loop around:

```
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "D:\...\ComparisonTool\"
Dim template_doc As Word.Document
Dim spool_doc As Word.Document

Dim spool As String
Dim templ As String
spool = Dir$("D:\...\ComparisonTool\spool*.txt")
Do While spool <> vbNullString
    templ = "template" & Left$(Left$(Right$(spool, Len(spool) - 5), _
            Len(spool) - 4), Len(spool) - 9) & ".docx"
    Set template_doc = Documents.Open("D:\...\ComparisonTool\" & templ)
    Set spool_doc = Documents.Open("D:\...\ComparisonTool\" & spool)

    Application.CompareDocuments OriginalDocument:=Documents(templ) _
        , RevisedDocument:=Documents(spool), Destination:= _
        wdCompareDestinationNew, Granularity:=wdGranularityWordLevel, _
        CompareFormatting:=False, CompareCaseChanges:=True, _
        CompareWhitespace:=False, CompareTables:=True, CompareHeaders:=True, _
        CompareFootnotes:=True, CompareTextboxes:=True, CompareFields:=True, _
        CompareComments:=True, CompareMoves:=False, RevisedAuthor:="UOB", _
        IgnoreAllComparisonWarnings:=False

    spool = Dir$
Loop
```

NOTE: I shortened the directory names to get rid of the side scrolling - you'll need to replace them with the actual directory path.

Comment: sorry to ask, but is spool* supposed to remain that way? Also templ should be changed back to template right? I'm very new to this so i apologize if I'm asking obvious questions.. The line of code starting from Application.Compare documents has an error when i change templ back to template.

Comment: Also, i changed Dim template_doc As Word.Document to Dim template_doc As Documents. Likewise for the spool one, as the spool files are actually .txt files. Does that affect anything? Thanks so much for your help, Comintern!

Comment: @JunJie - Yes.  It's exactly like typing `Dir spool*.txt` in a console window.  `templ` is the name of the variable that the matching file name goes in.

Comment: @JunJie - You need to leave the `As Document` as is.  Document is the type of object for the variable.  The only thing you should change from the code posted above is to replace the `"D:\...\ComparisonTool\"` with the original `"D:\Users\tmp4jj\Desktop\ComparisonTool\"`.

Comment: Theres an error as it reads the template files as a .txt file. Only the spool files are in .txt and the template ones are in .docx. The error lies in this line: "Set template_doc = Documents.Open("D:\Users\tmp4jj\Desktop\ComparisonTool\" & templ)" is there any way to fix this??

Comment: @JunJie - Does it give you an error, or just not do anything?

Comment: It's an error, sorry for the confusion, I missed out a word earlier and thought the code wasn't working at all. It's a run-time error 5174 where the specified file can't be found. The code is searching for template1.txt but my template files are all in docx.

Comment: @JunJie - Doh!  I totally missed the different file extensions.  See the edit.

Comment: Great its working! Thanks a bunch! One more question, do you know how to save the compared results automatically in a pre-designated folder? What happens now is that the compared files are opened in a new Word document. Is it possible to set a destination for it to be saved automatically?